# Como personalizar un confirm de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, .net, sweetalert

Necesito personalizar un confirm de js en el momento de que un usuario quiera eliminar una información.

Ya he intentado pasarle funciones las cuales acepta pero no borra la información solo enseña la alerta.

[image: Este es el confirm por defecto del navegador]

Quiero implementar uno más amigable como los de Sweet Alert o otro que no sea el común.

Utilizo este codigo desde VB.NET en el boton para llamar el confirm basico

```html
<asp:Button ID="btnDelIdio" runat="server" Text="Eliminar" Visible="False" CssClass="btn-delete" OnClientClick="javascript:if(!confirm('¿Desea Eliminar el idioma?'))return false" />
```

Comment: podrias revisar esto: https://forums.asp.net/t/2041859.aspx?custom+confirm+box

Comment: Ya que nombras **SweetAlert**, porque no utilizas ese?

Comment: no hay forma de modificar un confirm, "la solucion" es hacer ventanas modales y a fuerza de css javascript y html hacer el estilo deseado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los *confirm*, *alert*, etc son objetos del sistema y no pueden ser modificados por CSS. 
Para poder darle estilo deberías crear un elemento HTML e imitar la funcionalidad del *confirm*. 
Te dejo este enlace donde puedes ver como hacer con jQuery tu propio confirm o cualqueir *dialog* al que quieras darle tu propio estilo:

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation